# Vertical line limiter in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm sure I could google this and it's probably on SO already, but I can't even figure out what it's called. Is there an option in Visual Studio 2008 to activate that vertical dotted line that shows up x amount of spaces (normally defaults to 80) as a guide as to how long your lines of code should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: http://resharper.blogspot.com/2007/09/visualize-right-margin-in-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 3):

Also 'guidelines'

http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2004/11/15/257953.aspx